I try to build imageloader extension for mit app inventor using coil library, but i got compiling error
here is my complete project details.
coil image loader kotlin class.
package com.bibek.coilimageloader

import android.widget.ImageView
import coil.ImageLoader
import coil.request.CachePolicy
import coil.request.ImageRequest
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.SimpleFunction
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.AndroidNonvisibleComponent
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.ComponentContainer
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Image

class CoilImageLoader(container: ComponentContainer) : AndroidNonvisibleComponent(container.`$form`()) {

    private val context = container.`$context`()

    @SimpleFunction(description = "Loads an image from the given source (URL, path, or asset) into the specified Image component asynchronously using Coil.")
    fun LoadImage(source: String, imageComponent: Image) {
        val imageView = imageComponent.view as? ImageView
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("The provided component is not an ImageView")

        val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
            .crossfade(true)
            .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .build()

        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
            .data(source)
            .target(
                onStart = { placeholder -> imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder) },
                onSuccess = { result -> imageView.setImageDrawable(result) },
                onError = { error -> imageView.setImageDrawable(error) }
            )
            .build()

        imageLoader.enqueue(request)
    }
}


rush.yml
# For a detailed info on this file and supported fields, check out the below link:
# https://github.com/ShreyashSaitwal/rush-cli/wiki/Metadata-File

---
name: CoilImageLoader
description: Extension component for CoilImageLoader. Created using Rush.

version:
  number: auto
  name: '1.0'

authors:
  - Bibek Barman

build:
  release:
    optimize: true

  kotlin:
    enable: true

  desugar:
    enable: false
    desugar_deps: false

assets:
  icon: icon.png

deps:
  # Coil dependencies
  - coil-1.4.0.jar
  - coil-base-1.4.0.jar
  - coil-gif-1.4.0.jar
  - coil-svg-1.4.0.jar
  - coil-video-1.4.0.jar

  # AndroidX Lifecycle dependencies
  - lifecycle-common-2.4.1.jar
  - lifecycle-runtime-2.4.1.jar
  - lifecycle-livedata-core-2.4.1.jar
  - lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.1.jar

  # Kotlin Coroutines dependencies
  - kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.6.4.jar
  - kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.6.4.jar

  # Okio dependency for Coil
  - okio-2.10.0.jar


proguard-rules.pro
# Keep public class for the CoilImageLoader extension
-keep public class com.bibek.coilimageloader.CoilImageLoader {
    public *;
}

# Keep package names for specific classes
-keeppackagenames gnu.kawa**, gnu.expr**

# Optimization and repackaging settings
-optimizationpasses 4
-allowaccessmodification
-mergeinterfacesaggressively
-repackageclasses 'com/bibek/coilimageloader/repack'
-flattenpackagehierarchy
-dontpreverify

# Coil
-dontwarn coil.**
-keep class coil.** { *; }
-keep interface coil.** { *; }

# AndroidX Lifecycle
-dontwarn androidx.lifecycle.**
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }

# Kotlin Coroutines
-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.**
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.** { *; }

# Okio (dependency of Coil)
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class okio.** { *; }

# Handling common superclass issues for Coil and Coroutines
-keepclassmembers class kotlinx.coroutines.** {
    *;
}
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.** {
    *;
}
-keep class android.os.Handler {
    *;
}
-keep class coil.decode.BitmapFactoryDecoder$ExceptionCatchingSource {
    *;
}
-keep class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation {
    *;
}
-keep class kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl {
    *;
}

# Handle HandlerContext specifically for kotlinx.coroutines.android
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext {
    *;
}


dependencies jar files
[here is my dependencies files scrinshot](https://i.sstatic.net/buAjOrUr.png)
i compile this kotlin class using CLI based rush extension builder.
when i try to compile the kotlin.class for building extension, i got this error
E:\Extensions\coil-image-loader>rush build -r
                      __
     _______  _______/ /_
    / ___/ / / / ___/ __ \
   / /  / /_/ (__  / / / /
  /_/   \__,_/____/_/ /_/

• Build initialized

┌ Checking project files
│ info Checking metadata file (rush.yml)
│ info Checking AndroidManifest.xml file
└ done
┌ Compiling sources
│ info Picked 1 source file
└ done
┌ Processing the extension
│ info Linking extension assets and dependencies
│ info Optimizing the extension
│ note there were 1313 duplicate class definitions.
│            (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#duplicateclass)
│      Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
│        Class       = [kotlinx/coroutines/android/HandlerContext]
│        Method      = [<init>(Landroid/os/Handler;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V]
│        Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [android/os/Handler] (with 2 known super classes) and [kotlinx/coroutines/android/HandlerContext] (with 2 known super classes))
│
│ erro java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [android/os/Handler] (with 2 known super classes) and [kotlinx/coroutines/android/HandlerContext] (with 2 known super classes)
└ failed

• Build failed [57s 334ms] [1 error]

have any solution?

You might get better help if you ask in the App Inventor community in category Open Source Developnent - Extension Development
